# Expertise in C#,java

Tags: c#, java

I am a novice in c#,java and i want to become Professional in both in 2 to 4 weeks.Can anyone please specify me the correct and exact way of achieving my goal.By exact way i mean,what practices to follow,what books to follow,what all available online resources best for me and what all projects to work on from novice to professional

Comment: from novice to professional in 4 weeks.lol

Comment: Would you also become a chess master in 4 weeks from a complete novice? Mastery in any field takes time.

Comment: A professional car driver is a racing car driver. Do you think (s)he learned that in 4 weeks?

Comment: Why do you need two weeks? You only need 48 hours: Sams Teach Yourself C# in 24 Hours - http://www.informit.com/library/library.aspx?b=STY_Csharp_24hours and Sams Teach Yourself Java 2 in 24 Hours - http://www.informit.com/library/library.aspx?b=STY_Java2_24hours

Comment: If your target is 2-4 weeks, then forget if. Development path is not for you. To become professional it takes time and a lot of effort.

Comment: Hey, why set your sights so low?  Why not aim for (say) becoming Prime Minister of Australia?  The job is vacant at the moment, and they are going to fill it in 3 weeks time ...

Comment: Are you sure that you not make a joke ?

Answer (score 12):

You can't become a professional Java or C# programmer in 4 weeks, let alone both.

I suggest you read [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

Comment: Maybe the guy is a freaking prodigy. You never know.